# Notepad++: reemplace ocurrences of characters before other character

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have a file with text like this:

> "Title" = "Body"

And I would like to remove both " before the =, to leave it like this:

> Title = "Body"

So far I managed to select the first block of text with:

> .+(=)

That selects everything up to the =, but I can't find how to reemplace (or delete) both " .

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=.*=))[^"=\v]*\K"` and replace with an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a capture group in the replacement, and match the double quotes to be removed while asserting an equals sign at the right.

**Find what:**

```
"([^"]+)"(?=\h*=)
```

- `"` Match literally
- `([^"]+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ times any char other than `"`
- `"` Match literally
- `(?=\h*=)` Positive lookahead, assert an `=` sigh at the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q1kw50/1)

**Replace with:**

```
$1
```

[image]

---

To match the whole pattern from the start till end end of the string, you might also use 2 capture groups and use those in the replacement.

```
^"([^"]+)"(\h*=\h*"[^"]+")$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EIzSJe/1)

In the replacement use `$1$2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=.*=))[^"=\v]*\K"
```

Replace with an empty string.

**Details**:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=.*=))` - end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!^)`) or (`|`) start of a line that contains `=` somewhere on it (`^(?=.*=)`)
- `[^"=\v]*` - any zero or more chars other than `"`, `=` and vertical whitespace
- `\K` - omit the text matched
- `"` - a `"` char (matched, consumed and removed)

See the screenshot with settings and a demo:

[image]